# Is there any difference between svg and png img?

Tags: android

I am working on a project and   dont know which img to use for my icons.
 I have already tried searching the web but could not find the exact differnece.

Comment: There are plenty of differences. First google result for svg vs. png: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/249/which-format-is-better-for-saving-images-intended-for-websites-png-or-svg

Comment: Svg image : you can apply your own color filter but with png image you can't. So for example you want your image to be white and black at some point, with svg image you need only 1 image but with png you required two images

Comment: @jmargolisvt i guess you missed the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVGs are vectors, meaning they’re completely customizable. Change the size to big or small,  change the colors, or even change the shapes themselves. They will not pixelate as they scale making it great for multiple devices

PNGs come as they are. You can paste or place in any program with any background. You can’t really change the color or shape or the shape and if you try to make them bigger, they will pixelate.

Comment: and what about the XML files for the image?

Comment: svg files are pure xml.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support SVG. PNG simply for the fact it seems to be a more accepted format than SVG. SVG is scalable, if you have a vector-graphic that is a clear advantage. For pixel-graphics PNG is better but you could create one graphic that looked great on a tiny mobile phone screen or on a 60-inch computer monitor.